# Is it possible to load .obj file with colors if I don't have .mtl?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-model, objloader

I'm new to three.js and I came up to this problem. I made a 3D scan of my face and it gave me only .obj file. If I open that file on Meshlab model comes with color on it. But after I load it on three.js it is without texture.

```
            
    
            // Loader 
            
            const loader = new OBJLoader();

            loader.load( './models/scene.obj', 
            function ( OBJ ) {
            
            var boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( OBJ );
            boundingBox.getCenter( OBJ.position ).negate();
            
                scene.add( OBJ );
                
            },
            
            

            function ( xhr ) {

                console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

            },
            

    function ( error ) {

        console.log( 'An error happened' );

    }
);
```

[It's how my 3D model looks on three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr26w.png)

also it's one-sided from the wrong side

Also tried this solution but that's not working. "An error happened" shows up without explanation

```
objLoader.load('assets/faceimage9.obj', function(object) {
  scene.add(object);
  object.traverse(node => {
    if (node.material) {
      node.material.vertexColors = true;
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you for your answers!

Edit: My .obj looks like that at first ~50000 lines [image: My obj]
and then like this  [image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing one of your OBJs in this thread?

Comment: I get an error when I try to insert full .obj "An error occurred submitting the edit" If its not enough I can try to insert full file again.

Comment: Screenshots of your OBJs raw data are not helpful. Consider to upload the asset to something like Google Drive and share a link.

Comment: I uploaded google drive below screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OBJ asset defines vertex colors in the range [0,255] which is not supported by `THREE.OBJLoader`. Color data have to be defined in the normalized [0,1] range. Unfortunately the OBJ spec does not mention vertex colors so applications do not consistently export such data.

A simple fix to improve the rendering of your asset in `three.js` is this:

```js
objLoader.load('assets/faceimage9.obj', function(object) {
  scene.add(object);
  object.traverse(node => {
    if (node.material) {
      node.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
    }
  });
});
```

In this way, the faces should be correctly displayed (but without vertex colors).